# Use of $- in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

What is use of $- in Unix. In My system, the output is,

```
$ echo $-
himBH
$
```

what is meant by himBH? what it stands for.

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It returns the current shell's flags. The `$-` variable contains the shell's flags currently active in your terminal. These flags determine how your shell will function for you. In your case, these flags have the following meaning (note that all of these are defaults):

- **h**: Short for “hashall” (read that “hash all”), this tells bash to
  remember the locations of commands it has found through querying your
  PATH.
- **i**: Short for “interactive”, which is good, because this is a shell
  with which I’m interacting (entering input & getting back output)!1
- **m**: Short for “monitor”, this enables job control in bash (so you can
  send jobs to the background via bg, for instance).
- **B**: Short for “braceexpand” (read as “brace expand”), this allows you
  to use the very efficient brace expansion in bash2.
- **H**: Short for “histexpand” (read as “hist [history] expand”), this is
  what enables you to re-run a command from your history by prefacing
  its number with an exclamation point3.

These flags can be changed by using the `set` command. For example :

```
set +H 
echo $- 
himB
```

remove the `H` flag. Whereas `-`

```
set -H
echo $- 
himBH
```

restores it. That's it, a bit confusing but `+` removes a flag, whereas `-` adds a flag.

---

*More info:*

- [Bash man](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters)
- [Tutorial](http://www.chainsawonatireswing.com/2012/02/02/find-out-what-your-unix-shells-flags-are-then-change-them//?from=@)

Comment: So, Here 'h' stands for hashall. So, it tells bash to remember the locations of commands it has found through querying your PATH. So, If I disable 'h', then what will be happen. The bash did not find the PATH and failed to execute the command. Is it right.